# How to get a html document's readyState value with Rational Robot from IE?

Tags: automated-tests

I want to check a IE document's readyState value from Rational Robot.
The purpose of this is to signal Rational Robot that the page has loaded and it can continue testing and the delayfor tag would be removed.
Any ideas are welcomed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this command that returns a string containing the html document's readyState value.

sqagetproperty (" type=HTMLDocument;Index=1 "," readyState ",ready)